# Recommendations for clipless pedals that can be used with regular shoes

Tags: product-rec, pedals, shoes, clipless

Does anybody have recommendations for clipless pedals that can be used with regular shoes?  I only have 1 bike, but I use it enough that I think clipless pedals would offer a nice advantage.  However, I want to be able to just hop on my bike with any shoes, in the event that I'm just biking a short distance, and going to be walking around a lot.  I suppose I could get shoes that are more walking friendly, but I think it would suit me more to have pedals which accomodate both clipless and regular shoes.

Comment: Check the local second hand market as single sided pedals are often dumped by people who buy them and discover that they don't work for them. Once they get used to clipless many people become irritated at the extra fiddling of turning the pedal the right way up before clipping in, which double sided pedals (or 4 sided for Frogs) don't make you do.

Comment: Also, I ride occasionally on SPDs just street shoes and it works OK. Wouldn't want to do 50km like that but for 10 minutes it's fine. And I assume you've seen the mirror question: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3906/spd-shoes-that-look-like-normal-shoes My "normal" shoes have SPDs in them :)

Comment: You also might be trying to solve a problem that doesn't need to be solved.  Clipless pedals aren't necessarily an advantage.  Some food for thought: http://www.rivbike.com/article/clothing/the_shoes_ruse

Comment: Iantius's link has moved to http://www.rivbike.com/Articles.asp?ID=255

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been using Shimano A530 pedals for that purpose. Mountain SPD-compatible clip on one side, with a nice wide flat platform on the other.

I've also used the old Shimano M324 pedals, but prefer the slightly lighter weight and lower profile of the A530s.

Note that other foot retention systems, such as PowerGrips and the like, will work with all shoes (such as winter boots) and many existing platform pedals.

Comment: Seconded on the A-530s. I have used them myself for two years and have never regretted the purchase.

Comment: I ended up getting a pair of Shimano A530 pedals.  A little on the pricey side for my first set of pedals, But I'd rather buy expensive once than cheap 3 times over.  I also looked at the Shimano M424 pedals, but I liked the fact that the A530 had a full platform on one side.

Comment: I have A530s as well, coming from a similar perspective: I wanted the option to go clipless without the immediate commitment to do so, and the A530s have worked fine for me in regular shoes. Although the pedals are weighted so that the clipless side is up, it's not too difficult to flip them, and you can pedal a short distance if you just can't get the flat side up right away and need to get moving.

Answer (score 2):

Crank Brothers Mallets are good for this. They offer plenty of grip (when not clipped in) and aren't too heavy for what they are (472g for mid-range Mallet 2). They are also much more reliable than the earlier Crank Brothers' pedals.

[image: Mallet 2]

Answer (score 1):

I use the very cheap Wellgo WPD982, it depends on your price range, probably you should go for better pedals, but my experience with these has been good and I ride with and without SPD shoes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get a pair of Shimano SPD pedals and get the 'snap on' flats for one side. You'll only be able to clip on one side then but you'll also have flats on one side.

Another option would be to look at a downhill style pedal with a large platform on it. As long as the SPD portion isn't raised too much you can probably use them quite comfortably with regular shoes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the newer "hybrid" pedals that have both a clipless side and a platform side with grip for regular street shoes.

http://bicycling.about.com/od/allaboutyourbike/ss/bike_pedals_8.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Forte Campus/Nashbar Rodeo/Wellgo WPD-95B (all are similar Wellgo dual sided SPD clones with different brand names) for thousands of miles, and am very satisfied with them. There's also the Nashbar Highlander if you want a big BMX-type body on the pedal. All can be found for $30 or so; the Rodeo is on sale for $20 right now.