# Are there any cleats (for SPD-SL) that convert the pedal to a regular flat platform for regular shoes?

Tags: pedals, shoes, clipless

I have a road bike that use Shimano 105 PD-5800 SPD-SL pedals and they are wonderful when exercising. However I would like to be able to use the bike with regular shoes for more casual use of the bike, but I also don't want to exercise unnecessary wear and tear on the pedals by not using a cleat. Are there any cleats (for SPD-SL) that convert the pedal to a regular flat platform for regular shoes?

I know that this question is similar to [this one](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/recommendations-for-clipless-pedals-that-can-be-used-with-regular-shoes) but I ask for a special cleat that converts the SPD-SL pedal to a regular flat platform and not a hybrid platform. I want to keep my Shimano 105 PD-5800:s since I really enjoy them.

Comment: There are a handful of devices available that amount to a flat plat you can attach a cleat to the bottom of and clip into your pedal, and some people have made their own.  I know these were mentioned once or twice in other threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a ready made part, see [Fly Pedals](http://flypedals.com/).

This is essentially just a metal platform, which you bolt cleats onto, then clip them into your pedals. They are threaded with holes for 2-bolt or 3-bolt cleats, so should work with most mountain bike or road bike clipless pedals (including SPD-SL).

Note these are not yet available, but you can pre-order them from the Fly Pedals website. Some more details on [Fly Pedals on Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1513937573/flypedals-universal-clipless-bike-pedal-adapter) - that page says delivery from end of July 2014.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't find any factory made component, you can always get down the do-it-yourself route.

Here is a link to set of instructions on how to make ones for Shimano PD 520/540:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Pedal-platforms-for-Shimano-PD-520540/

The basic idea of it is to get hold of an extra pair of cleats, affix them with appropriate bolts to a suitable small platform that somehow resembles a non cleated pedal and add some sort of anti slippage material to it.

If you ever have attached your shoes to your pedals while not wearing them, you'll find not difficult to install and remove such contraption from your pedals.

However, I have never used this type of adaptor (I've been very tempted though) but I assume this is just for leisure pedalling, like a short trip to the corner store, I woluld not advise to use them for training, racing, stunts nor any type of demanding riding.

Since you mention loving your pedals, (wich I think means you really really like using your cleated shoes) I would advise to better carry your normal shoes and change them while you arrive to your destination. A small saddlebag, a stylized handlebar bag, or even a small backpack is a convenient solution to carry both your normal shoes while riding, and your cleated shoes while walking.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is not the correct style (question is for SL)

This is the Shimano part number

SHIMANO SM-PD20

I have some and they are a pain. The are hard to insert and remove and you have to spin the pedal to get the correct side up.  I would rather swap out pedals.

This is a reflector but not sure if it is meant to step on [reflector insert](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Pedals/SI-PD22D-001/SI-PD22D-001-ENG_v1_m56577569830661952.pdf)

Comment: I see. They seem to be for the SPD mount and not the SPD-SL mount though. If there are a counterpart for SPD-SL that are not meant to be stepped on I may need too consider changing pedals often instead.

Comment: I missed the SL.  Will delete when you get a correct answer.

Comment: No problem. You could just edit the answer pointing out that you know of an official insert for a related system. I'm sure it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question. But in case anybody stumbles upon this while trying to figure out the answer, as I did, I did find these:

http://www.bikedabs.com/

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @D-Lo. Usually we would say *please summarize the link in case it dies*. But in this case there wouldn't be much point :-) Nice find.

Comment: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.