# Which dual-platform clipless pedals allow for the least amount of movement between the pedal and sneaker

Tags: pedals, clipless

I am trying to decide between the A530 or PD-M324.  I am interested in hearing from folks who have used both.  Weight isn't the most important factor in my decision, so I would go with whichever model is grippier.  If they're more or less equal in that department, I would be inclined to go with the A530 since it's a bit lighter.  I wear flat-soled sneakers most frequently.

I've looked at this thread, which provides suggestions on how to improve the grippyness of the A530 (leading me to believe that they are somewhat slippery):

[How do I make the platform side of a Shimano PD-A530 multi-purpose SPD pedal less "slippery"?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4368/how-do-i-make-the-platform-side-of-a-shimano-pd-a530-multi-purpose-spd-pedal-les)

Comment: "grippiness" is kind of a subjective thing, I think. I'm not sure that, as it stands, your question is a particularly good fit for this site.

Comment: If you usually wear sneakers then get some large platform street or downhill pedals.  Combined with bicycle sneakers you get an excellent grip.  When you want ride clipped in then switch out.  Two sided pedals are not very good at either.

Comment: The A530 definitely leaves something to be desired in the grippiness deparment.  I haven't used the PD-M324 but from the looks of it, it looks quite a bit better. The thing to watch out for is that the platform side will usually be facing down on both these models due to how they are weighted.  If you're going to be switching between clipless and platform, you should probably error on the side of more grip, because once you're used to clipless, every platform pedal seems to not have enough grip.

Comment: Another model worth considering is the [Shimano XT 780 Trekking](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ca/en/shimano-xt-t780-spd-trekking-clipless-mtb-pedals/rp-prod67250) model.

Comment: I did try the A530 at a bike shop.  The surface offered little resistance and I could easily slide my dry shoe across the top when pressure was reduced.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Set of PD-M324's in my box of bits. Plenty grippy, to the point unless you are extreme down-hilling or free riding I doubt you need better. I have double sided caged SPD's with a cage similar to the look of the A530, also in my box of bits - no where near grippy enough, especially when wet. They are good for MTBing when you are unclipped alot - when learning SPDs or technical ground and lack of confidence, but now I am riding less technical XC I do not need them.

Its not possible to make a grippy pedal that also has an SPD - how would you rotate to  release the clip?  Single sided pedals are a great idea that does not work very well most of the time for most people. Inevitably the side you want is facing down when you put your foot on the pedal. You cannot be certain, without looking, which way it is, so you cannot rely on the pedal when you need it quickly. They are OK for casual riders and might work acceptably for roadies who are not stopping a lot for traffic, but for me, and others I have spoken to who have tried them, they are just frustrating.

I now always ride with my SPD's. If I was to start riding sneakers/street shoes, I would go to a caged SPD, and wear the slippages, but those rides would be down to the local store with the family. If you are not prepared to wear the slippages, go to proper platforms and discard the SPD's altogether, or swap pedals when you want to change styles.

How badly do you want SPD's? Have you considered getting some SPD compatable sneakers/street shoes?

If you do go ahead with the single sided pedals, I recommend the PD-M324, but consider something like the M647 (Clips both sides with cages).